# How can I change icon of the node according to the attribute automatically in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, icons

I'd like to change icon of the node according to the attribute automatically/dynamically in Flex.
Bellow are my codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           width="540" height="610" chromeColor="#E8E50A">
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XMLList id="user_list">
        <node user="Running Center">
            <node user="System Administrator">
                <node icon="admin" user="admin" type="admin"/>
                <node icon="home" user="root" type="home"/>
            </node>
            <node user="Common User">
                <node icon="user" user="Udo" type="user"/>
                <node icon="user" user="Steven" type="user"/>
                <node icon="user" user="Peter" type="user"/>                    
            </node>         
        </node>
    </fx:XMLList>
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        [Embed(source="assets/admin.png")] 
        public var admin:Class; 

        [Bindable]
        [Embed(source="assets/home.png")] 
        public var home:Class; 

        [Bindable]
        [Embed(source="assets/user.png")] 
        public var user:Class; 
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:Tree id="user_tree" 
         x="10" y="51" width="206" 
         height="207" dataProvider="{user_list}"
         iconField="@icon" labelField="@user" showRoot="true" />
</s:Application>
```

Here is the effect image:

I'm sorry for I can't post an image.
Bellow is the link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZG6v.jpg

For example,maybe I should change the code like this?

```
<node icon="{...}" user="admin" type="admin"/>
```

Any help is greetful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you would really just want to modify the dataProvider so that the icon property changes... I suppose maybe I'm not understanding the problem.

Comment: I'd like to change the icon according to the "type" attribute.If I add a node(<node user="admin" type="admin"/>) which "type" is admin,the icon of node will be "asset/admin.png".Of course, in the code there will not exist "icon='admin'".The code I put above is the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some Google results for: "Flex tree iconFunction"

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/11/15/creating-a-custom-icon-function-on-a-flex-tree-control/

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/11/15/setting-a-custom-icon-field-in-a-flex-tree-control/

Comment: I really appreciate your help @adrian-pirvulescu.The answer met parts of my need.Maybe I should rebuild my XMLList.